# Code coverage for trigger reducing to zero while deploying

Tags: trigger, unit-test, deployment, code-coverage

I am having a trigger for which I wrote a test class, I run the test class in my sandbox, it is giving 17 percent coverage, but when I deploy it and run specified test classes with the test class, I get code coverage error saying 0 percent coverage it has. I have created data in the test class and not fetched it using a query.
Not sure what is happening. Below is the trigger and its test class

```
trigger updatelookups on Payment_Schedule__c (before insert, before update) {
    for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++)
    {
        if(Trigger.new[i].Proforma_Invoice_No__c!=null)
        {
            System.debug('aaa'+Trigger.new[i].Proforma_Invoice_No__c);
            Performa_Invoice__c PI = [Select Id, RFP__c,Vendor__c,Total_Executed_Cost_With_Freight__c,Total_Executed_Cost_With_F_And_Tax__c,Indian_Logistics_Invoice_Currency__c, PI_Total_Amount__c,Customer__c,Customer_Contact__c,Indian_PI_Currency__c,Invoice_Type__c from Performa_Invoice__c where id=:Trigger.new[i].Proforma_Invoice_No__c];           
            Trigger.new[i].Customer__c = PI.Customer__c;
            Trigger.new[i].Customer_Contact__c = PI.Customer_Contact__c;            
            Trigger.new[i].Order__c = PI.RFP__c;
            System.debug('bbb'+PI.Id);
            System.debug('ccc'+PI.PI_Total_Amount__c);

            if(PI.Invoice_Type__c == 'Proforma Invoice')
            {
                Trigger.new[i].Currency__c = PI.Indian_PI_Currency__c;
                //Trigger.new[i].Amount__c= PI.PI_Total_Amount__c ;
                Trigger.new[i].Amount__c= PI.Total_Executed_Cost_With_F_And_Tax__c;
                System.debug('ddd'+PI.Id);
                System.debug('eee'+PI.PI_Total_Amount__c);  
                System.debug('fff'+Trigger.new[i].Amount__c);  
            }
            else if(PI.Invoice_Type__c == 'Logistics Invoice')
            {
                //Trigger.new[i].Amount__c= PI.Total_Executed_Cost_With_Freight__c; 
                Trigger.new[i].Amount__c= PI.Total_Executed_Cost_With_F_And_Tax__c;          
                Trigger.new[i].Currency__c = PI.Indian_PI_Currency__c;  
            }
            else if(PI.Invoice_Type__c == 'Tax Invoice')
            {
                Trigger.new[i].Currency__c = PI.Indian_PI_Currency__c;
                Trigger.new[i].Amount__c= PI.Total_Executed_Cost_With_F_And_Tax__c;
            }
        }
        else if(Trigger.new[i].Purchase_Order_No__c!=null)
        {
            Purchase_Order__c PO =[Select RFP__c,Amountpo__c,Vendor__c,Currency__c from Purchase_Order__c where id=:Trigger.new[i].Purchase_Order_No__c];
            Trigger.new[i].Vendor__c= PO.Vendor__c;
            Trigger.new[i].Amount__c= PO.Amountpo__c;
            Trigger.new[i].Order__c = PO.RFP__c; 
            Trigger.new[i].Currency__c = PO.Currency__c ;         
        }
        else if (Trigger.new[i].Logistics_Plan__c!=null)
        {
            Logistics_Plan__c LP = [Select RFP__c, Selected_Logistics_Name__c, Selected_Depot_Name__c, Plan_Cost__c from Logistics_Plan__c where id=:Trigger.new[i].Logistics_Plan__c];
            Trigger.new[i].Amount__c= LP.Plan_Cost__c ;
            Trigger.new[i].Order__c= LP.RFP__c ;
            Trigger.new[i].Logistics_Vendors_Contact__c = LP.Selected_Logistics_Name__c ;
            //Trigger.new[i].Logistics_Vendor__c = LP.Selected_Logistics_Name__r.Logistics_Vendor__c;
            Trigger.new[i].Depot_Vendors_Contact__c = LP.Selected_Depot_Name__c ; 
            //Trigger.new[i].Depot_Vendor__c = LP.Selected_Depot_Name__r.Logistics_Vendor__c;
        }       
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class updatelookupsTest 
{
    @isTest
    static void init(){
        Account acc = new Account(name='Test Account');
        insert acc;        

        Order od = new Order();
        od.Name = '14TPE000001';
        od.AccountId = acc.Id;
        od.EffectiveDate = Date.Today();
        od.Status = 'RFP Creation';
        insert od;  

        Payment_Schedule__c p = new Payment_Schedule__c();    
        p.Cheque_Number__c='1';
        p.Amount__c = 123;
        p.Order__c = od.id;
        insert p;
        p.Amount__c = 222;
        update p;
    }   
}
```

Comment: That can only happen when you do not write test class properly, like hardcoded Id's, rely on orgs data, etc. Its hard to comment without seeing your code.

Comment: @AfrozKazi are you getting any error? check debug logs

Comment: Best place is to see debug logs, you likely might have some validations blocking something. That's why ALWAYS use asserts to validate expected vs actual functionality!

Comment: @RohitMourya No. No errors. The test class exectes fine in sandbox and while deploying i dont get any errors apart from code coverage error.

Comment: @AfrozKazi Your test class seems to be find. If you're deploying it to production then you must have atleast 75% code coverage.

Comment: @RohitMourya the required coverage for trigger is 1 percent. In sandbox it is 17 which goes down to 0 in production in my case

Comment: @AfrozKazi Looking at your test class, i dont think any block of your trigger code is getting covered as none of the condition that you have in if else blocks seems to be meeting the criteria.

Comment: Are you sure that you're also deploying your test class when you're deploying your trigger? Beyond that, I would take a step back and make some improvements to your trigger. As is, your trigger is not 'bulkified', and you will run into errors if you happen to insert/update more than 100 `Payment_Schedule__c` records (and perhaps sooner, depending on what other triggers you have).

Comment: @DerekF I thought same thing but OP specifically stated they were running the test on deployment. You may be right though as if you type a test name to run and it does not exist I do not think any error is thrown so it is most likely the case

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for help. I tried a lot of things for this deployment. I even reached 75 percent coverage still was unable to deploy. Every time the production deployment failed saying 0 percent coverage it had. I even tried with 95 percent coverage. Still it didnt work. So finally tried with 100 percent coverage and it worked.